# Django asking to define `model` while its already defined

Tags: python, django

I have already defined `model = Post` in my views.but still its asking for defining a model or queryset! where am i doing wrong then?

views.py

```
from .models import Post
from django.views.generic import ListView
# Create your views here.
class PostList(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.ListView.as_view(),name ='list')
]
```

traceback error

```
File "D:\django\blog_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\django\blog_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\django\blog_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\django\blog_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\django\blog_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\django\blog_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py" in get
  142.         self.object_list = self.get_queryset()

File "D:\django\blog_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py" in get_queryset
  39.                     'cls': self.__class__.__name__

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /
Exception Value: ListView is missing a QuerySet. Define ListView.model, ListView.queryset, or override ListView.get_queryset().
```

Comment: You write `ListView.as_view()` instead of `PostList.as_view()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined a `PostList` view class, but forgot to use that class-based view, and instead used the `ListView` parent class. You thus need to replace:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.ListView.as_view(),name ='list')
]
```

with:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(),name ='list')
]
```

Otherwise Django will use the `ListView` class, and that one is missing the `model` and `queryset` attribute (deliberately), since the idea is to specify it at the level of real (non-abstract) class-based views.

Answer (score 1):

In the *urls.py* you should have used your actual view name, which is `PostList` and you used the *django* class from which you inherited `ListView`.

`urlpatterns` should look like this:

```
urlpatterns = [path('', views.PostList.as_view(),name ='list')]
```